# How Are POCO Controllers Discovered As Controllers?

Tags: asp.net-core

How does the framework know my [POCO is a controller](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview) if it does not inherit from the `Controller` base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some conventions that we use to identify a POCO controller:

1. The assembly must reference MVC
2. The POCO controller class must have the suffix Controller

Comment: I'm curious if we'll be able to write our own conventions.

Comment: @MikeSW any reason why?

Comment: @dfowler Because I want to choose the criteria that turns a POCO into a controller. It's about giving me, the developer, control over the framework. Defaults are good, but I want the power to _easily_ override them if I need it. And it's trivial to implement support for our own conventions.

Comment: I just wanted a concrete and realistic example, I'm not pushing back. What you said was pretty a generic "Because I should be able to"

Comment: @dfowler "EndPoint" is a perfect example. `ProductsEndPoint`, I hate to keep bringing this up, but you should take a serious look at what FubuMVC (rip) did.

Comment: @dfowler or even a namespace convention would be another custom convention for Controller discovery.

Comment: @dfolwer while you at it, make View discovery convention based also... :-) Dont get me wrong, I'm loving what you are doing with MVC6, we are getting closer! Needless to say we are excited about the changes.